# Fit function hmmlearn doesn't work: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: scikit-learn, hmmlearn

I am trying to run a hidden markov model, however the fit function doesn't work properly.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn import hmm

X1 = [[0.5], [1.0], [-1.0], [0.42], [0.24]]
X2 = [[2.4], [4.2], [0.5], [-0.24]]

X = np.concatenate([X1, X2])
lengths = [len(X1), len(X2)]

hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths)
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-cdfada1be202> in <module>()
      8 lengths = [len(X1), len(X2)]
      9 
---> 10 hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths)

TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: try doing: `.fit(X, lengths=lengths)`

Comment: hmmlearn is a scikit-style library, not scikit-learn. And this error has nothing to do with scikit-learn. So please change the question title.

Comment: @Harpal It doesn't work..

I get this error message:

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lengths'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of `hmmlearn` you have and update that. The `lengths` param is available in newer versions as seen here

http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hmmlearn.hmm.GaussianHMM.fit

Then try doing (as @Harpal suggested):

```
hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths=lengths)
```

Comment: I checked it and have the newest version.

However, when clicking on the source/code, it can be seen that the function expect his:

def fit(self, X, lengths=None)

Comment: @JoepvanderPlas I am on version 0.2.0 and not getting any error on your code. Can you tell your version?

Comment: @JoepvanderPlas I am not able to duplicate this. I have hmmlearn 0.2.0 and scikit-learn 0.19.1. Checked both on python2 and python3. Are you sure you are using the same versino which you are telling here. Maybe you installed it on other location. Try  `import hmmlearn` and `print(hmmlearn.__version__)`. from the current script.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be reproduced for `hmmlearn` 0.1.1,

however if you do a `pip install hmmlearn==0.2.0` in your virtual env and follow up with `hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths=lengths)`.

Things should work out just fine!